# Que significa "libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x, pygame

El juego funciona y todo pero una vez pierdas o ganes te parece este mensaje en el compilador (En mi caso uso spyder)

```
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: Interlace handling should be turned on when using png_read_image
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: Interlace handling should be turned on when using png_read_image
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: Interlace handling should be turned on when using png_read_image
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

Porque pasa esto? y como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Por lo que recuerdo ese un error devido a que .PNG tiene  formatos muy viejos y parece que windows no puede leerlos correctamente, te anexo un link sobre lo que puede hacer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374187/qt-open-a-jpg-file-with-warning-image-format-not-supported sin embargo el link es para QT en C no en python pero si sabes un poco de programación sera suficiente para traducirlo, independientemente de esto solo te arroja un warning no un error, por lo que si tu programa corre sin problemas esta no deveria de preocpuarte

Comment: El problema es causado por el formato png ya que algunos usan un antiguo formato, no es nada grave, en mi caso en Linux yo uso el comando `convert` para actualizar el formato., supondo que debe haber algo similar en windows